# How to only display when hover?

Tags: html, css, hover

I want to show a playbutton when you hover over the image. This is my HTML:

```
<a href="bekijk.php?film_id=2014">
    <div class="geheel">
        <h3>Text</h3>
        <div class="vidimg" style="background-size:200px 110px; height:110px; width:200px; 
        background-image: url(img/film/2014.png);">
            <div class="playknop" style="height:100px;width:200px;">
                Playbutton
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
.playknop                   {display:none;}

.playknop:hover + .playknop {display:block;}

.geheel                     {width:200px;}
```

It's not working. Is there anyone who knows why?
Thank you.

Comment: You can not hover over something that is not visible …

Comment: Currently you defined a hover effect for the button, not the image.

Comment: You shouldn't put some of your CSS inline and some in a separate file. Put it all in a separate file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to do something for you with only css, and it works, but you should order it as you like.

you can view example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/SLB4S/1/

I did that when you hover the image than the play button will pop

```
div#hoverMe:hover > #playBtn{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: if the answer is good, please approve it for others to enjoy it.

Answer (score -1):

you can use javascript for this or you can use `z-index` for this

Comment: How? This doesn't answer the question